# Get value from object of unknown content by key in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm writing function that'll return single value from object by key or return empty object if key does not exist.

Code:

```
//example data:
const obj = {
    data: {test: 'word'},
    str: 'Hi',
    num: 22,
}

const pickOne = <T extends object>(obj: T, key: keyof typeof obj) => ((key in obj) ? obj.key : {})

console.log(pickOne(obj, 'data')) //should print {test: 'word'}
```

My problem is that I get this error: `Property 'key' does not exist on type 'T'`.
I'm new to typescript but after reading docs I was sure that `keyof typeof` would allow any key in `obj`.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It is worth using `T extends Record<string, unknown>` instead of `T extends object`. Because `object ` is very wide type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
obj.key
```

gets the property named `"key"` on `obj`, which may not exist.

Where this:

```
obj[key]
```

Gets the property name *in the variable* `key`.

Which works without type error: [See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1&ts=4.6.2&ssl=8&ssc=86&pln=8&pc=94#code/PTCmA8EMFsAcBtQAIAmkAukBcBYAUAMYD2AdgM7pJEBGAVkgLxIDe+S7qG2L6oFWSAOQB3IgCcUggL4AaNhwpiBggBIBLQXLwckJAK7QBAJiNap+fMXKVYaggGsA8iWRMAPABUkEXiRRkqOlACdAA+AAoaWgEPGSR7UABPAQTEogAzJHRE2FAMwNoASkZQpHDw1KQ1EgLigH4CgG1UgF0kAWYpQotCUjIiRAA6eCIAc3DbB2dQSLo4wTRMQULikDIACyI9eBQkWDFqymZefiFRCWkgA)

Answer (score 2):

Your `obj` has 3 keys:

- `data`
- `str`
- `num`

When you write `obj.key` you are telling the interpreter to find a key called `key`, which does not exist.

On the other hand you can access these keys by its *name* using brackets:

- `const key = "data"`
- `obj[key] // Should return {test: 'word'}` , which is equivalent to:
- `obj["data"] // Should return {test: 'word'}`

### Moral of the story:

1. The dot-notation is to access existing keys in a given object

   - If the key exists it works. Otherwise, it errors out
2. TypreScript also allows accessing these keys by name

   - If the key exists it works. Otherwise, doesn't error out but returns `undefined`

Working example:

```
const obj = {
    data: {test: 'word'},
    str: 'Hi',
    num: 22,
}

const key = "data"
console.log(obj[key])
console.log(obj["data"])
console.log(obj["key"])
```